# Actionscript 3 hide overflow of a sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, sprite, invisible

I am trying to create a sprite in Actionscript 3 using Flash Professional with fixed width and height that contains a list of TextFields that scrolls up and down.  I want the highlighted textfield to be fixed focus with the text that goes out of the sprites bounds to be invisible.  I am new to AS3 and tried to set the width and height of the sprite but it did not work.  I would do this with CSS by having a  with a fixed width and height and setting the overflow property to hidden.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ScrollPane component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa2.html) as you can set a fixed width and height for the content and choose to automatically show scroll bars for the pane.

Answer (score 1):

Add a mask to the sprite to contrain what is visible, http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/06/dynamic-masks-using-sprites-in.html

Comment: a better solution would be to use the `scrollRect` property: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect - combine it with `cacheAsBitmap` and you've got a highly efficent scroller (as masking and using `scrollRect` without `cacheAsBitmap` will redraw the entire region when it moves, even though a small part is visible - `scrollRect` plus `cacheAsBitmap` will only redraw the rectangular part